# Azure project templates not visible in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I'm trying to the install the latest version of the Windows Azure SDK on Windows 7 using the Web Platform Installer. The installation succeeds but I'm not able to see Windows Azure project templates in Visual Studio 2010. Any ideas are appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.

1. Uninstalled Visual Studio 2010 Express
2. Repaired and did a complete install of Visual Studio 2010
3. Installed the Azure tools and SDK manually

Not sure why it worked but it did. Thanks for all the answers!

Also see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/aa8cdf32-fca0-4a81-bf47-659345696047

Answer (score 2):

In a vanilla install of Visual Studio 2010 (SP1) they should be there automatically in the folder "Cloud". There you can download the Azure Tools to actually use them.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff687127.aspx

Comment: The vanilla install of Visual Studio 2010 (SP1) won't give you the project templates. The project templates are installed with the Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. Read the article again.

Comment: That's right, that's what I said: it should shows the instructions to download the Azure Tools to actually install them. If the Cloud folder is not there in the first place, something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know whether you can see the “Cloud” folder on the left side of the new project dialog. If not, please try to run the following command:

Devenv /resetsettings

When you first run Visual Studio, a dialog may be prompted for you to choose a setting. Please make sure to choose general developer settings. If you choose other settings, certain project templates may be hidden.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: I chose the general developer settings when I installed and launched VS the first time but still I couldn't see the Cloud folder in the new project dialog. I'm now re-installing visual studio and then re-install the Azure Tools & SDK. If that doesn't work I'll run the command you're suggesting.

Comment: Re-installed VS2010 SP1 and the Azure Tools and SDK but still the same issue.  Devenv /resetsettings did not help. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have the following folder on your machine:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Cloud

You can use “Program Files” instead of “Program Files (x86)” if you’re on a 32 bit machine. If Windows Azure is installed, you can see project templates under this folder.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: I uninstalled everything from my host and created a brand new Win 7 x32 SP1 virtual machine with just SQL Server 2008 R2 Express SP1, VS2010 SP1 and then installed Azure Tools for VS2010 and the Azure project templates still don't show up. I can't see any "Cloud" folder being created in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp. No “Program Files (x86)” folder as the virtual machine is a 32 bit. However I see now that there is "Cloud" folder in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\. 
What’s wrong!?

Comment: I copied the "Cloud" folder from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress\ProjectTemplates\CSharp to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp and the ran the command Devenv /resetsettings but still no luck!

Comment: If I run the Visual Studio 2010 Express I'm able to see the Cloud project templates. Why does the Web Platform Installer install Visual Studio 2010 Express when I already have Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed!!? This is really crap! Taken up 72 hours to install a SDK and still not solved. How can it be only me who is experiencing this problem?
 
Is there a solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Windows Azure SDK manually by downloading individual  msi's from here (depending on your machine arch) http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28045
and see if you are running into an error for any one of them.

(WindowsAzureTools.VS100.exe should install the project templates)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a version of Visual Studio where you can create Web projects and things like that?  Maybe it is a problem with the version.  Can you create MVC projects?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.